# What is the Rust equivalent of Rx's `startWith`?

Tags: iterator, rust

Is there any predefined function to start iteration with a custom element using Rust's iterators?

Comment: Iterators and reactive streams are not the same thing though. You might want to look at [futures::stream](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/stream/index.html) instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> iteration with a custom element

If you have a single element, use [`iter::once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.once.html).

If you have multiple elements, use [`iter::repeat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.repeat.html) coupled with [`Iterator::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take).

> to start iteration with

Use [`Iterator::chain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain).

Put together:

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let some_iterator = 1..10;

    let start_with = iter::repeat(42).take(5);

    let together = start_with.chain(some_iterator);

    for i in together {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```